# Split string (object) into two columns on a character delimiter but KEEP character delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I am trying to split a column into two columns on a character and want to keep the character delimiter.

I have tried str.split() and it splits the columns the way I want but it deletes the character delimiter (as it is supposed to).

My column looks like this.

```
   mor
0  HR Ncfsa
```

I am using this code:

```
df[['mor1', 'mor2']] = df['mor'].str.split(pat='^[A-Z]', n=-1, expand=True)
```

I get

```
   mor1   mor2
0         R Ncfsa
```

But I want to keep the first letter of the original column to get:

```
   mor1   mor2
0  H      R Ncfsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['mor'].str.extract('^(?P<mor1>[A-Z])(?P<mor2>.*)$')
```

[out]

```
  mor1     mor2
0    H  R Ncfsa
```